# Which Regular Expression should be used here?

Tags: python

I have a list of urls :

```
print (url_list)     

[https://www.reddit.com/r/funnyvideos/comments/qfvclx/winners_of_the_rfunnyvideos_oscars_2021/,
      https://v.redd.it/5tmm5wx5lgz71,
      https://v.redd.it/n35a5fo8cez7,
      https://v.redd.it/3j0sexqs8ez71,
      https://v.redd.it/cmy0l1roxfz71]
```

How to filter this list so that only the urls with only `v.redd.it/` are provided in output and all others urls are exlcuded.

This is what I meant (possible output):

```
Your required urls :

https://v.redd.it/5tmm5wx5lgz71,
  https://v.redd.it/n35a5fo8cez7,
  https://v.redd.it/3j0sexqs8ez71,
  https://v.redd.it/cmy0l1roxfz71

Excluded Urls :

https://www.reddit.com/r/funnyvideos/comments/qfvclx/winners_of_the_rfunnyvideos_oscars_2021/
```

I am new to regex and python, so please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `[url for url in url_list if "v.redd.it" in url]`

Comment: can you please explain the difference between your comment and the answer below. both of it works btw

Comment: @RJAdriaansen That will pass with `v.redd.it` anywhere in the url, not just URLs pointing to the `v.redd.it` host.

Comment: @MatsLindh you're obviously right. But there seems little chance of multiple occurrences of this string in the urls. If so, `[url for url in url_list if url.startswith('https://v.redd.it/')]` would suffice.

Comment: Sure, until you get a `http` url in your list for some weird reason. It's better to handle the actual requirement (which is a oneliner it itself) than adding each exception we find.

Comment: @Sainita my answer just does string matching, no url validation as it seemed overkill to me. Having checked it, `urlparse` is actually faster so just go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a regex to do this, instead you can filter your list based on whether the host of the URL is `v.redd.it` (and get proper url parsing instead of implementing a regex to attempt to do the same):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/funnyvideos/comments/qfvclx/winners_of_the_rfunnyvideos_oscars_2021/', 'https://v.redd.it/5tmm5wx5lgz71', 'https://v.redd.it/n35a5fo8cez7']
v_redd_it = filter(lambda x: urlparse(x).netloc == 'v.redd.it', urls)

# you can then either iterate over the filter directly, or convert it to a list

video_links = list(v_redd_it)
# ['https://v.redd.it/5tmm5wx5lgz71', 'https://v.redd.it/n35a5fo8cez7']
```

Comment: [url for url in url_list if "v.redd.it" in url] , this also works, can you please explain the difference . trying to learn

Comment: You won't confirm that `v.redd.it` is actually the host in that case; you'll end up with `https://www.google.com/search?q=v.redd.it` passing the check, even though the _actual_ host isn't `v.redd.it` - it's just present in the URL somewhere.

Comment: Hello again :) , i am trying to get the filtered output inside a dictionary, this is my code :  new_dict = dict({v_redd_it}) , however iam getting this error : ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required  , how to fix it, pls help

Comment: What are you planning to have as the key/value pair in the dictionary? The syntax you've given creates a set, then attempts to create a dictionary from that set. Since a dictionary requires a key:value pair for each entry, giving it a single list or set doesn't have any meaning.